# Cannot Perform Linq-To-Sql Stored Procedures with MVC-Mini-Profiler

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, c#-4.0, mvc-mini-profiler

I am using the MVC-Mini-Profiler in my ASP.net 4.0 C# environment along with MSSQL and Linq-to-SQL.  I am having an issue with using L2S with the profiler.  Whenever I return new DataClassesDataContext(),  it allows me to get data from L2S stored procedures. But if try to return the Mvc-Mini-Profiler ProfilesDbConnection, I can get the data from the stored procedure on the first time after I build, but then ever time after that, zero data is returned.  When it returns the DataClassesDataContext using ProfiledDbConnection, I can still iterate through the Db tables, but for some reason, the stored procedures do not allow me to send/receive data.  Any ideas on why this might be?

```
try
{
    var miniProfiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
    var connstring = new DataClassesDataContext().Connection.ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring);
    var profiledConnection = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(connection);
    var context = new DataClassesDataContext(profiledConnection);
    return context;
}
catch
{
    return new DataClassesDataContext();
}
```

Comment: no repro here ... can you include a full failing sample? Can you make sure you are running the latest version from nuget